# Maximum principle for non-homogenous Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Assume $\Omega$ to be a bounded open region in $\mathbb R^n$, and $u(x)\in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$, which suffices
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-\Delta u+c(x)u=f(x) ,x\in \Omega\\
u|_{\partial\Omega}=0
\end{array}\right.$$
where  $c(x)\geq c_0\geq 0$. How to prove that $\displaystyle\max_{x\in\bar{\Omega}}\left|u(x)\right|\leq \frac{1}{c_0}\sup_{x\in\Omega}\left|f(x)\right|$?
Can we transform the operator $-\Delta u+c_0u$ to $-\Delta v$ for some function $v$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need $c_0>0$ for your inequality to make sense. Suppose that $R>0$ is sufficiently large such that $\Omega \subset B_R$ and let $v$ satisfy $-\Delta v +cv = 1$ in $B_R$, $v=0$ on $\partial B_R$. Since $c$ is nonnegative the strong maximum principle implies that $v>0$ in $\Omega$. Since $v$ is zero on $\partial \Omega$, $v$ must attain its maximum at some point $x_0 \in B_R$. At $x_0$ we have that $-\Delta v(x_0) \geqslant 0$, so $$1 \geqslant c(x_0) v(x_0) \geqslant c_0 v(x_0). $$ Hence, $$ v \leqslant \frac 1 {c_0} \qquad \text{in }B_R. \tag{$\ast$} $$

Now let $w:= u - \max_{\overline{\Omega}} \vert f \vert v.$ Then $w \leqslant 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ (since $v \geqslant 0$) and \begin{align*} 
-\Delta w + c w &= f- \max_{\overline{\Omega}} \vert f \vert \leqslant 0
\end{align*} in $\Omega$. The maximum principle implies that $w \leqslant 0$ in $\Omega$, whence $$u(x) \leqslant \max_{\overline{\Omega}} \vert f \vert v(x) \leqslant \frac 1 {c_0} \max_{\overline{\Omega}} \vert f \vert  $$ by ($\ast$).

Similarly, by considering $w:= u + \max_{\overline{\Omega}} \vert f \vert v$ we obtain $$ u(x) \geqslant - \frac 1 {c_0} \max_{\overline{\Omega}} \vert f \vert$$ which completes the proof.

*Note:* In order to prove $(\ast)$ we needed to assume that $v$ was a classical solution, that is, $v \in C^2(B_R)\cap C(\overline{B_R})$. This requires some regularity assumption on $c$ ($c\in C^\alpha(\Omega)$ is enough). If you can't make such an assumption then you will need to to adjust the proof of $(\ast)$ somehow.